# keep-alive header defaults

Tags: http, http-headers

I ran a bunch of tests on a heavy PHP script with a bunch of image processing functions with apache bench (ab).

When I modified my PHP scripts to exclude the keep-alive HTTP header (instead of using "keep-alive: timeout=1, max=20"), the speed report was about 30% faster. If I added the keep-alive header with the timeout and max values specified, the speed will then be slower again.

I ran all tests with 20 simulated users and 20 connections for each.

I'm running apache with php connected via DSO/ModRuid2. In my apache config, I have keepalive timeout set to 1 second.

I'm trying to figure out the default values for keep-alive HTTP header if values are omitted, and I'm trying to figure out if the values are imported from elsewhere in the system.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

By default the ab ignores the Keep-alive headers -- as per the ab documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

> `-k Enable the HTTP KeepAlive feature, i.e., perform multiple requests within one HTTP session. Default is no KeepAlive.`

So it seems unlikely that turning on and off the Keep-Alive on your server is causing the problem.

HOWEVER... Your server using Keep-Alive will send a ping to the client and wait for a response. It should be a quick ping/ack and if it doesn't get a quick acknowledgement your server should drop the connection, but it is possible that because ab doesn't answer that your web server is cluttering up the pipe with unnecessary connections.

Try it ab -k to see if that changes your results.